# 502 Server Error on (GRPC Transcoding) REST API and 200 OK on GRPC - Cloud Endpoints on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc-python

After having deployed my GPRPC server on GKE with ESP and Cloud Endpoints api_config file, I am able to test correctly (200 OK) the requests using the GRPC client but all CURL requests using REST API transcoded fail with a weird : "502 Server Error - The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.Please try again in 30 seconds."

I never have this issue before. It look like the Ingress part is not always built correctly. Sometimes it works, sometimes it fails.

Do you have some clues from where this might come from ?

Answer (score 0):

I have referred to the docs [Getting started with Endpoints for GKE with ESP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-kubernetes-engine#objectives) and [Deploying a service that uses transcoding](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding#deploying_a_service_that_uses_transcoding) and successfully deployed a GRPC server on GKE with ESP, Cloud Endpoints and CURL requests using REST API transcoded in my environment.

While deploying the ‘Getting started with Endpoints for GKE with ESP’ doc, I made few modifications as follows:

1. Used [grpc-bookstore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/endpoints/kubernetes/grpc-bookstore.yaml) configuration file which doesn’t need Ingress service.
2. Add roles “Service Controller” and “Cloud Trace Agent” even if the node service account is the Compute Engine default service account.

While [Deploying a service that uses transcoding](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding#deploying_a_service_that_uses_transcoding), I made few modifications as follows:

Used below python command,

```
   python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc \
     --include_imports \
     --include_source_info \
   --proto_path=${GOOGLEAPIS_DIR} \
     --proto_path=. \
     --descriptor_set_out=api_descriptor.pb \
     --python_out=generated_pb2 \
     --grpc_python_out=generated_pb2 \
   http_bookstore.proto
```

to create the descriptor file.

Change service’s target port to 8080 in grpc-bookstore’s configuration file.

Try this and let me know if you face any errors.